# m2e Maven Repositories View - cannot see snapshots

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

When I look at my snapshots repository in Maven Repositories View, I only get

[image: Empty Snapshots View]

I checked that the repository exists and is reachable from my computer (it is also not empty and in Nexus, the index of it works fine). I also checked the other repositories and everything is fine with them (also in eclipse). Rebuilding or Updating the index does nothing (not even writes an error to the eclipse .log).

When I delete everything from the .m2 directory, I *sometimes* get a view of snapshots, but is usually lost again quite soon and cannot be recovered.

Any idea why the snapshots repository index is not read or created?

Comment: According to the screenshot attached there this seems to be the same effect as described in [\[m2e-users\] m2eclipse Maven Repositories view refuses to show me contents of Nexus Repo](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/m2e-users/msg00175.html). No solution there but trying it with a more recent m2e version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran "repair index" as admin on Nexus. This resolved the issue (apparently).